# R: rgl layout3D breaks playwidget in RMarkdown

Tags: r, rgl

I'm creating a Rmarkdown report where I use a `layout3D()` multiple plot and a `playwidget()` plot with a slider. If I run the code as below everything works fine but if I want to display the multiple plot first and the slider after (so just changing the order of the last two cells) I got the slider broken with all points displayed and the slider not making any change in the widget. Same problem if I want to display a slider, then a multiple plot and then another slider: the first slider works fine but the second doesn't. I guess it's something related to the output of multiple plot that remains "linked" to the following slider.

An additional (probably related) question is how to group all the multiple plot in a single object to be returned by the function, as for the slider one. That's why I need to add `rglwidget()` after the function call in order to display the plot in the cell.

Thanks

````
---
title: Test
output:
  html_document
---


```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, fig.height = 13, fig.width = 13}
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(rgl)))
options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE) # Suppress the separate window.

# define function
fun_playwidget = function(){

clear3d()    
setosa <- with(subset(iris, Species == "setosa"), 
     spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                  col=as.numeric(Species),
                  radius = 0.211))
versicolor <- with(subset(iris, Species == "versicolor"), 
     spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
               col=as.numeric(Species),
               radius = 0.211))
out = rglwidget() %>%
playwidget(start = 0, stop = 1, interval = 1,
       subsetControl(1, subsets = list(
                 Setosa = setosa,
                 Versicolor = versicolor
                 )))

return(out)
}

fun_layout3D = function(){
  shapes <- list(Tetrahedron = tetrahedron3d(), Cube = cube3d(), Octahedron =  octahedron3d(),
               Icosahedron = icosahedron3d(), Dodecahedron = dodecahedron3d(),
               Cuboctahedron = cuboctahedron3d())
col <- rainbow(6)
open3d()

mat <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
mat <- rbind(mat, mat + 4, mat + 8)
layout3d(mat, height = rep(c(3, 1), 3), sharedMouse = TRUE)
for (i in 1:6) {
  next3d()
  plot3d(shapes[[i]], col = col[i])
  next3d()
  text3d(0, 0, 0, names(shapes)[i])
}
}
```

# playwidget
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE, fig.height = 5, fig.width = 5, webgl=TRUE}
fun_playwidget()
```

# layout3d
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE, fig.height = 5, fig.width = 5, webgl=TRUE}
fun_layout3D()
rglwidget()
```
````

EDIT: it seems that the `rglwidget()` after the `fun_layout3D()` corrupts the rendering making the round points being plotted as squares as in figure (data are different)
[image]

EDIT 2: Here's the minimal example. This produces both issues: point are rendered as squares and the slider doesn't move.

````
---
title: Test
output:
  html_document
---


```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, fig.height = 13, fig.width = 13}
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(rgl)))
options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE) # Suppress the separate window.

# define function
fun_playwidget = function(){

clear3d()    
setosa <- with(subset(iris, Species == "setosa"), 
     spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                  col=as.numeric(Species),
                  radius = 0.211))
versicolor <- with(subset(iris, Species == "versicolor"), 
     spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
               col=as.numeric(Species),
               radius = 0.211))
out = rglwidget() %>%
playwidget(start = 0, stop = 1, interval = 1,
       subsetControl(1, subsets = list(
                 Setosa = setosa,
                 Versicolor = versicolor
                 )))

return(out)
}

fun_layout3D = function(){
clear3d()
  mat <- matrix(1:2, ncol = 2)
  layout3d(mat, height = c(2,2), widths = c(2,2), sharedMouse = T)
  data = matrix(sample.int(100, 81), ncol = 3)
  next3d()
  plot3d(xyz.coords(data), col = "blue", type = "p", size = 30)
  next3d()
  plot3d(xyz.coords(data), col = "red", type = "p", size = 30)
  rglwidget()
}
```


# layout3d
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE, fig.height = 5, fig.width = 5}
fun_layout3D()

```

# playwidget
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE, fig.height = 5, fig.width = 5}
fun_playwidget()
```
````

Comment: Looks like a bug in the code to reuse objects.  Use argument `reuse=FALSE` in the second `rglwidget()` call and it seems to work.

Comment: BTW, you should use `rglwidget()` or `webgl=TRUE`, not both.

Comment: @user2554330 if you switch the position (`fun_layout3D()` first and then `fun_playwidget()`) it doesn't work, even with `reuse=FALSE`

Comment: @user2554330 moreover, any idea on how to return the plot in `fun_layout3D()` so to avoid the external `rglwidget()`? Thanks

Comment: Please include a minimal example that fails, and only ask one question at a time.

Comment: @user2554330 Done, see the EDIT 2 in the original question

Comment: That doesn't include `reuse=FALSE`.